# When is destroy() method called in HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory class?

Tags: java, spring

I have created CloseableHttpClient object as shown below. I am trying to understand when will the destroy method in HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory class be called? I tried debugging by terminating the application but the destory() method is not called when the application is terminated.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();

return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` as a `Bean`.
It becomes managed by the Spring bean factory, which will call the factory's `destroy` method when the application is closed, or the bean goes out of scope. The `destroy` method of the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` will close the underlying `ClientConnectionManager` connection pool.

```
@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory() {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
}
```

`HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` implements `DisposableBean` interface

See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html) or [Destruction Callbacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean):

> Interface to be implemented by beans that want to release resources on
> destruction. A BeanFactory will invoke the destroy method on
> individual destruction of a scoped bean. An ApplicationContext is
> supposed to dispose all of its singletons on shutdown, driven by the
> application lifecycle.